# WPF Resize Window from Bottom to top

Tags: c#, wpf, window, height, size

I really need help for this questions, I search everywhere but can't seem to find an answer. I have a window with the height set to 66. In my code behind I have a button on the bottom of the the window. when the user clicks this button(this.height = 400), the size of the window is to grow from bottom up. but it grows from left top corner. please help :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change how the controls are anchored in the window.  They are going to default to anchoring to the top left, so when the window size changes, the controls will not move.  If you anchor the a control to the bottom, then when the window grows, the control will move down accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds to me as if you want to decrease the `Top` property value of your WPF Window by the same value that you increase its `Height`, or rather its `ActualHeight` effectively.

There is also an `Expander` control in WPF that you might find useful.

Comment: thank you guys for your answers. but I think I should have explained my issue a bit better. i have a grid which the initial height is zero. when a button is click, i want this grid's height to grow upwards. but the direction it is growing right now is down. the bottom (where the button is) should remain in same position. just the grid height should increase upwards.

Comment: @user2799177: I'd say the behavior you observed is by design: changing `Height` of something dynamically does not affect its `Top` value automatically. So that if you want to keep the resulting "Bottom" where it previously was, you'd need to decrease the `Top` value as soon as you increase the `Height` value, because "Bottom" is the result of `Top` + `ActualHeight`

Comment: @user2799177 The comments on *someone's answer* aren't really the best place to provide more details about *your question*. Try editing your question to include this extra information; some XAML would also be useful as your question is really about WPF layout.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your answers. I finally solved this issue by using a popup. I attached it to the top of the window and when its height is increased, it increases from bottom up.

> Popup Text