# How do I grow this window from Bottom to Top?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this window with dynamic content. Increasing the text of the TextBlock increases the height of the window as well.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
    SizeToContent="Height"
AllowsTransparency="True" 
    WindowStyle="None" 
    Background="MediumPurple"
    Topmost="True" MinWidth="478" MinHeight="124"
    >
<!--Background="{x:Null}"-->
<Grid  Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="SlateGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Name="SubTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,32" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <TextBlock.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Black" Opacity="1" Direction="0" BlurRadius="5" />
        </TextBlock.Effect><Run Text="bla bla bla vla dasd gsfg duryktry ytrjhryt ju5635jtyjk tuk tej tu k ti56u46u234 h jreyjry dssfgf dss"/></TextBlock>

    <Rectangle Name="Mainrect"  Fill="#FFC31A1A" MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown" Margin="0,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.6,1.75" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <Rectangle.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Select *.SRT file..." Click="MenuItem_Open"/>
                <MenuItem Name="resize_mitem" Header="Enable Resizing" Click="Resize_mitem_OnClick"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Impostazioni"  Click="MenuItem_Settings" IsEnabled="False"/>
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Esci" Click="MenuItem_Quit"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Rectangle.ContextMenu>

    </Rectangle>
    <Grid Name="Playstop" MouseLeftButtonDown="Playstop_OnMouseLeftButtonDown"  Margin="10,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20" ToolTip="Play / Stop">
        <Rectangle Fill="#00ff00" />
        <TextBlock Name="GlyphPaused" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,-1,1">▶</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock  Name="GlyphPlaying" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,1" Visibility="Collapsed">❚❚</TextBlock>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Name="IncreaseLatency" MouseLeftButtonDown="IncreaseLatency_OnMouseLeftButtonDown"  Margin="0,0,10,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20" ToolTip="Play / Stop">
        <Rectangle Fill="#0000ff" />
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="18" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,-3,1,-1">➕</TextBlock>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Name="LowerLatency" MouseLeftButtonDown="Playstop_OnMouseLeftButtonDown"  Margin="0,0,40,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20" ToolTip="Play / Stop">
        <Rectangle Fill="#0000ff" />
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="18" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,-3,1,-1">➖</TextBlock>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

## The problem

My problem here is that when window size is increased my controls slide down. I'd like to have fixed controls and the new textblock space sliding up.
[image: the problem]

I am looking for a XAML solution, if possible. Else anything will be fine.

---

## Update

I came up with this, but it flickers.

`Private Sub MainWindow_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
        Dim ps = e.PreviousSize
        Dim ns = e.NewSize
        Dim delta As Integer = ns.Height - ps.Height
        Me.Top -= delta
    End Sub`

Comment: That means when you change the size of your window you also want to change it's position, since the position of the window changes when the upper left corner moves. Take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28512395/1456174

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix I added a code snippet I came up with. The OP of that question you linked to says he solved using `WPF Popups`. I am investigating, but it doesn't look like the solution for this problem (I may be wrong, tough).

Comment: Try changing SizeToContent to Manual.  I would suggest using a RichTextBox for the scrolling-to-bottom-automatically feature.

Comment: All the text needs to be visible so scrolling-to-bottom is not viable. I will try setting SizeToContent to Manual.

Comment: Also set VerticalAlignment on TextBox to Bottom

Comment: Why not just put the controls at the top of the window, where they would be stationary even if the window grows?

Comment: Because it should act like a subtitle